Does SwiftData give a model a primary key?
If I use @Model to tell SwiftData to persist a class with its properties, does it add a property to use as a primary key?
And if so, is it an incrementing integer?  What is it called?
Is that key used to persist the foreign keys for related records in other tables?
Here's an example.
@Model
class MICCard {
    var suit: MICSuit
    var faceValue: MICFaceValue
}


It adds a unique identifier property to your class.

SwiftData is not a database. It is an abstraction over <insert thing that can persist data here>. The documentation never mention "primary key" at all. Primary keys don't exist at the level of abstraction that SwiftData is at.
So the answer to your question solely depends on the implementation details.
On iOS 17.4, SwiftData uses a CoreData container under the hood, and CoreData uses a SQLite database under its hood for non-in-memory containers. You can find this SQLite database by printing the url of a ModelConfiguration. Then you can inspect it using a SQLite client. Based on my observations of this file,

Each of your model's tables will have a primary key column called Z_PK, which seems to just be an incrementing integer. You cannot access this in your @Model class, because the @Model class is at a much higher level of abstraction.
Even if you have a @Attribute(.unique) property, it will not be the primary key of the table.
Relationships are represented with a column that references the Z_PK column.

Related question: can we set primary key in core data

If you just want a unique identifier for your model, there is the id property. With a model context, you can find the model identified by this ID.
